# apache2 access log , thousands of logs from the IP of the same server

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, page-speed, mod-pagespeed

I was Trying to read the apache access log for my vps `1.1.1.173`  server and i have found something 
wired , it has almost 98% of the requests from same IP address of  the vps here is an example of logs

`1.1.1.173 - - [02/Feb/2012:16:39:58 +0400] "GET /css/demo_table.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9933 "-" "Serf/0.7.2 mod_pagespeed/0.10.19.5-1253"`

it counts `23943` form this ip , how to explain that ??

notes : 
i had mod pagespeed enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_pagespeed has an agent, Serf, which is fetching the non-optimised version of the page.  So every request into your system with mod_pagespeed enabled looks like:

external client->mod_pagespeed/Serf proxy->real page.

I would expect every external request for a page mod_pagespeed hasn't optimised and cached to result in Serf request, which will comes from the server's own IP address.

Comment: your answer seems to be good , but could you please provide the prove of it , thanks

Comment: Have a read through: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/mod-pagespeed-settings/ which discusses the architecture and mentions Serf and explains the caching behaviour.